# Build a Backend that upload files to FTP

Tags: django, rest, soap

I have 2 mobile apps and a website that need a function that can upload some files in XML format to FTP. Hence I am thinking to build a backend that manipulates those XML files so that all 3 applications can use it. Should I be building a RESTful or SOAP API? I am thinking to build a restful api so the client side can pass data in json, as for the backend to FTP side I don't have much experience.

Comment: [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) is the best option for you

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, setting up a RESTful API would probably be the easiest and most straightforward approach. Using Django, you can leverage [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to setup the backend, and both Android and iOS interact with it, especially if you use tokens, or a [json-web-token](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt).

Using django-rest-framework, you can also upload files, as well as pull from the API from JSON, XML, and various other formats as well.

I think SOAP may be overkill, and from what I see, a lot more people are using REST versus SOAP in the current day and age.